# ¿Como implementar notificaciones IPN Mercado Pago, para pagos parciales?

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy usando ***checkout*** básico dando a los clientes la opción de pagar con dos tarjetas.

Uso el *SDK* de *PHP v 0.5.2* y tengo configurado escuchar el ***topic payments*** de las notificaciones ***IPN***.

*/collections/notifications/**[ID]**?access_token=**[ACCESS_TOKEN]***

Recibí la notificación, consulté el estado del pago y estaba aprobado, entonces entregué el producto, pero no tengo implementada la lógica de verificar si el monto del pago es el monto completo de la venta. Necesito saber si hay algún atributo en el pago que indique que es un pago parcial para *checkear* directamente esa variable, o ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de implementar esta funcionalidad?

Answer (score 3):

Si tenés implementado la opción de pagar con dos medios de pagos, te recomiendo escuchar notificaciones de *merchant_order* que es el objeto que contiene toda la información de una venta, y no vas a tener problemas con pagos divididos.

Aquí tienes [documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/basic-checkout/ipn/), pero básicamente éste es el código que deberías implementar

```
    // Get the payment and the corresponding merchant_order reported by the IPN.
if($_GET["topic"] == 'payment'){
    $payment_info = $mp->get("/collections/notifications/" . $_GET["id"]);
    $merchant_order_info = $mp->get("/merchant_orders/" . $payment_info["response"]["collection"]["merchant_order_id"]);
// Get the merchant_order reported by the IPN.
} else if($_GET["topic"] == 'merchant_order'){
    $merchant_order_info = $mp->get("/merchant_orders/" . $_GET["id"]);
}

if ($merchant_order_info["status"] == 200) {
    // If the payment's transaction amount is equal (or bigger) than the merchant_order's amount you can release your items 
    $paid_amount = 0;

    foreach ($merchant_order_info["response"]["payments"] as  $payment) {
        if ($payment['status'] == 'approved'){
            $paid_amount += $payment['transaction_amount'];
        }   
    }

    if($paid_amount >= $merchant_order_info["response"]["total_amount"]){
        if(count($merchant_order_info["response"]["shipments"]) > 0) { // The merchant_order has shipments
            if($merchant_order_info["response"]["shipments"][0]["status"] == "ready_to_ship"){
                print_r("Totally paid. Print the label and release your item.");
            }
        } else { // The merchant_order don't has any shipments
            print_r("Totally paid. Release your item.");
        }
    } else {
        print_r("Not paid yet. Do not release your item.");
    }
```

Comment: El endpoint /collections/notifications/ ha sido deprecado pueden ver la nota de deprecación aqui https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/localization/migrating-v0-v1